# Ubuntu 18.04 - How do I turn of desktop sliding

Tags: 18.04, gnome, multiple-monitors

Evening all,
  I've just upgraded my laptop to 18.04 after several years on 16.04.  I have a second monitor onto which I've extended my desktop.  This second monitor is 40" so I use it as my primary monitor.  When I move the mouse to over to the laptop built in screen the desktop slides across to show the laptop screen on the second monitor.  This is frustrating and awkward as I lose sight of half of what is displaying on my second monitor.  I've googled around for a couple of hours to find out how to turn this off but I've not had any luck.  This has never happened on any other version.

Any suggestions?

Regards

RobC

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have fixed this behaviour by turning off NVidia Optimus in the BIOS.  I set the BIOS to use Discreet Graphics.  Now I can move my mouse and windows to both screens without the desktop sliding left & right.

Regards

RobC